# How to provide partition key with Azure Stored Procedures

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am hitting my stored procedure API in azure Cosmos DB, but I am getting back the message

```
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header\"]}\r\nActivityId: afd48989-60b5-489d-95ce-e999fc5561c9, Request URI: /apps/497cb807-5f70-43d9-a68c-a742815f6016/services/fae8a265-85a1-4d9b-904e-7a996901d928/partitions/ecdbf51b-d1f2-46d4-8b42-9ddbbf39aa1a/replicas/131818407837945845p, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2018-10-15T18:08:20.5929270Z, Number of regions attempted: 1\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
}
```

I know *that* I need to provide the partition key, but I am unsure *how* to. Is it in the body? Provided as a header? I've tried both of these in Postman with no luck. Using Postman, how would you format your request to send the partition key to the stored procedure?

Examples I've tried (on a POST request)

1. Tried adding a header called "PartitionKey" with a value of 51.
2. Tried sending an array with the partition key `["51"]` in the body raw since the body is supposed to contain a parameters array.
3. Tried the following raw json body

   ```
   {
       "PartitionKey": "51"
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the cosmos db [Common REST request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers), you need to specify the partition key with `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` parameter.

```
{x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey : '51',...}
```